# how to reproduce an analytic view in SAP HANA database using the .analyticview xml descriptor file?

Tags: hana

I am trying to reproduce an analytic view that have already been modeled in one project within another project using the `.analyticview` XML file descriptor.

I managed to reproduce the required attribute views by copying and activating the `.attributeview` XML files to the new project. But when trying to activate the `.analyticview` I am getting this error:

> Internal deployment of object failed;Repository: Encountered an error in repository
>
> runtime extension;Model view/data not consistent:Deploy Model: Empty XML read from
>
> Repository for Dimension URI /path_to_attributeView/attributeviews/ITEM

Obviously the problem is that the analytic view is not able to read the attribute views. So, I tried to edit the path pointing to the attribute views in the `.analyticview` XML manually, I tried:

- using relative paths `./attributeviews/ITEM` since the attribute views and analytic view files are in the same folder.
- using absolute path, considering that the folder structure of the repository workspace is `folder1/folder2/data/name.attributeview` I added this path to the file but still getting the same error.

Could you please check what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1. Are the attribute views visible for the user you are using ?
2. If you are using HANA studio try to open the analytic view descriptor with the modeler editor to see what is wrong
3. It will be useful to attached the analytic view xml itself.

Comment: thanks for answering, I'll answer those question when I have access to the server on Monday! thanks again.

Comment: hi, 1/ the activation of the attribute views is successful but I am not able to expose them with OData

Comment: 2/ I couldn't open the analytic view from the project explorer window, and since there are errors detected within the file It doesn't exists in the project repo to open it with the GUI editor. I can open the attribute view with the GUI and there is no problem with it.