# Is it possible to create an analytic view as a persistent model in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

In SAP HANA database it is possible to create database objects like tables, views, schemas, sequences as persistent models. For instance, I create a `.hdbtable` file containing the description of a new table and the activation of the file would create a table in SAP HANA.

The question is whether or not it is possible to create attribute views and analytic views as persistent models.

I tried using the XML descriptor files generated by the GUI editor to recreate the views in a new project. This worked well for the attribute view where the activation of the `.attributeview` file creates a new attribute view however it did not work for the `.analyticview`.

So if it is possible to create the analytic view as a persistent model what are the steps to follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible just as you said: Get the xml representation create the appropriate .attributeview, .analyticview, .calculationview file and simply activate it. And of course be sure that your user is powerful enough to see and call all the needed artifacts.

Comment: yes, I tried to do that, however the .analyticview xml file has some path  that need to be changed from one project to another. The accurate question in my case is how to configure this path?

Answer (score 0):

that's a good question. I don't think analytic and attribute views are supported as persistent model. At least not that I know of. You can also check on help.sap.com/hana for the updated features. As of my writing, I don't see it's possible to do that.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. actually I was playing this this before, and I managed to create the attribute view which is very simple just copy and activate the file, however the problem is in the analytic view I already started a thread explaining this particular issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916045/how-to-reproduce-an-analytic-view-in-sap-hana-database-using-the-analyticview-x)